# Filling array with random numbers using Intel TBB

Tags: c++, random, c++11, parallel-processing, tbb

I have two different functions to fill a global array with random numbers: A serial version and a parallel version using lamba expression and TBB.

```
void get_data(void)
{
    int j = 0;
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    cout << "Generating random numbers ...\n";

for (j = 0; j < DATASIZE; j++)
    data[j] = (rand() % range) + range_min ;

}

void parallel_get_data(void)
{
    int j = 0;
    srand((unsigned) time(NULL));
    parallel_for(0, DATASIZE, 1, [=](int i) 
      { data[i] = (rand() % range) + range_min ; });

}
```

The program is running an Intel Xeon cluster but unfortunatly the parallel version is much slower. If instead of filling the array with random numbers I simply do a `data[i] *= 2` a speed up of up to 50 % can be measured. Has this something to do with the random function? Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: Calling `rand` concurrently is probably a bad idea. If the implementation is thread-safe, then it will have to lock access to the internal state each time you call it, which is just going to turn your parallel program into a sequential one. If it isn't thread-safe, then calling `rand` in parallel is just going to produce junk.

Comment: @JaredHoberock The locking can be eliminated by using thread local storage.

Comment: rand likely serializes, if you are using tbb look at using combinable & the C++11 random number generators to build a thread local random number generator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you're calling a function vs. executing a multiply instruction. Each time the function is called it has to set up the call frame, jump to the function, calculate the random number and return from the function. Add the stack manipulation, stack checking, etc. and it's going to be slower. About the only way to avoid it is to provide your own implementation of `random` and hope it can be inlined by the compiler.

Comment: Actually, the instruction pipeline (in particular the branch predictor) will eliminate most of the latency of these function calls (assuming they're not inlined - why would `rand() be non-inlinable`? )

Comment: @MSalters If it's in a shared library